# Hibernate and currentSession: "Heck, I don't want these transactions!"

Tags: java, hibernate

I substituted:

```
sessionFactory.openSession();
```

With:

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
```

And I added this configuration for Hibernate:

```
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```

Now I'm getting this error:

```
failureorg.hibernate.HibernateException: createQuery is not valid without active transaction
```

Why should I use beginTransaction() and so on, after I use currentTransaction? I don't want to use transactions... so, what should I change?

Comment: create transaction and your problem will be sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

You used `getCurrentSession`, not `currentTransaction`. Transactions are not optional in Hibernate—you *must* start a transaction.

The configuration you set up resulted in a session being opened for you automatically, but not a transaction within the session.

Comment: But when I use openSession() I don't have to start any transaction. Why?

Answer (score 0):

You can, skip beginning and committing  of transactions by spring integration and declaring your transaction as annotation driven